# show non-printable characters in TextEdit

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to redefine how some characters printed in QML TextEdit component?

Basically all I want is to replace all tabs with some "arrow" image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. But you can replace all tabs in text to display with an "arrow" character.

```
TextEdit {
   text: sourceText.replace("\t", "\u21E5") // ⇥
}
```

Hacky, but propably still the best option.